# How to get current year and month when using _onVisibleDaysChanged on TableCalendar Package

Tags: flutter, package

I have an issue to get the current month and year when swiping Calendar on the TableCalendar package. I have to use the **_onVisibleDaysChanged** but I don't understand how to get the current month and year with that.

this is the callback function

```
void _onVisibleDaysChanged(DateTime first, DateTime last, CalendarFormat format) {
    print('CALLBACK: _onVisibleDaysChanged');
}
```

the first and last is the visible calendar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

The controller can get the focused attribute, and when I combine that with onVisibleDaysChanged it will do like I want.

[This is my reference](https://github.com/aleksanderwozniak/table_calendar/issues/170#issuecomment-570803722)

Comment: Can you show how did you do that? I'm with the same problem

Comment: @0nroth1 You can use the controller of that package.

`_controllerCalendar.selectedDay` it will return DateTime, just like that.